# Is this a legitimate use of association?

Tags: c++, uml, associations, relationship

I have a sensor class, which has a name, location, data arrays. I want to make an association relationship between it and a widget (a series of print statements that take in a number as an input, so for example, "Press 1 to clear the sensor", "Press 4 to sort the values of the sensor"). I want to have the relationship between these two as "Widget MODIFIES sensor".

In the case of setting the sensor, could I have an association class that will record the time that the widget called for the sensor to set, the widget that called it and the sensor in question?

Answer (score 1):

In a UML class diagram, you can use a basic association to represent this relationship. If the multiplicity of the association is many-to-many (i.e. many widgets can modify a sensor and each widget can modify many sensors), then you can use an association class to break that and this would be a logical place to put information such as time stamps as you suggest. In theory, you don't need to specify a member on this association class to record the "widget that called" the sensor because that is already implicit in the association.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if  `Widget` and `Sensor` are associated, you can have an association class to specify properties that are specific to each instance of the association ("link").

However, your narrative suggests that there may be several alternatives with different meanings.  For exemple:  [image]

In your case,  if you want to wire the widget with the sensors to be controlled, but also want to have an history of the changes,  you may need two different associations with each a different purpose:  `controls` and `modified`.